# count even numbers in a list or vector in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to print the count the even number in a list via a loop, I don't get any results, I tried:
assign numbers into a:

```
a<-31415926535427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989380952572010654858632788659361533"
```

Then I split them:

```
a.c<-strsplit(piestring.c, "")
```

Then I unlist them:

```
a.cu<-unlist(piestring.c, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
```

Then I convert them to numerical:

```
a.cn<-as.numeric(a.cu)
```

Then I checked if it can get even numbers:

```
for (stev in piestring.cn) {
    if (stev %% 2 == 0) {
    print(stev)
        }
}
```

Then I tried to set counter:

```
counter <- 0
for (stev in a.cn) {
    if (sten %% 2 == 0) {
        counter <- counter + 1
    }
}
```

I get no results, is there an easier way to count the even number, then print the count of the even number in the first 50 digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a similar workflow to what you are using, you can use this to check the first 50 numbers. This uses all the same logic but adds `fixed = TRUE` to `strsplit()` for a small speed increase, and takes more advantage of vectorization.

```
sum(as.integer(strsplit(a, "", fixed = TRUE)[[1]])[1:50] %% 2 == 0)
[1] 22
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in single digit even numbers, you can the `stringr` library:

```
str_count(a, "0|2|4|6|8")

[1] 186
```

If you are interested in the first 50 numbers:

```
str_count(str_sub(a, 1, 50), "0|2|4|6|8")

[1] 22
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a new solution which using only base R functions (`gregexpr`) and it seems to be most efficient:

```r
length(gregexpr("0|2|4|6|8", substr(a, 1, 50))[[1]])
```

OP comments suggesting that a proper function should be offered for him:

```r
count_str <- function(x, what, first = NULL) {
stopifnot(is.vector(x))
stopifnot(is.character(what))
stopifnot(is.null(first) || is.numeric(first))
x <- unlist(x)
pattern <- paste0(what, collapse = "|")
length(gregexpr(pattern, if (is.null(first)) x else substr(x, 1, first))[[1]])
}

> count_str(a, c("0","2","4","6","8"), first = 50)
[1] 22
> count_str(a, c("0","2","4","6","8"))
[1] 186
> count_str(list(a), c("0","2","4","6","8"), first = 50)
[1] 22
> count_str(a, c("0","2","4","6","8"), first = 0)
 Error in count_str(a, c("0", "2", "4", "6", "8"), first = 0) : 
  is.null(first) || (is.numeric(first) && (first > 0)) is not TRUE
```

```r
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+ base = {length(gregexpr("0|2|4|6|8", substr(a, 1, 50))[[1]])}, 
+ stringi = {stri_count(stri_sub(a, 1, 50), regex = "0|2|4|6|8")}, 
+ stringr = {sum(str_count(str_sub(a, 1, 50), "0|2|4|6|8"))}, 
+ times = 10000)
Unit: microseconds
    expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq      max neval
    base 10.665 12.2195 15.16829 12.8520 13.636 520.857 10000
 stringi 11.858 12.6705 14.66833 13.5395 14.367  312.927 10000
 stringr 13.517 14.3300 16.49280 15.2950 16.030  218.752 10000
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work, for instance:`bbn="31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549"
stri_count(stri_sub(bbn, 1, 100), regex = "0|2|4|6|8")` it will get your out put of 51, try to delete three 2s, the output will come 50!

Comment: and the same thing with: `bbn="3141592653589793384664338379502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428"
tabl <- rle(sort(strsplit(bbn, "", fixed = T)[[1]][1:100]))` it will get your out put of 51, try to delete three 2s, the output will come 50!
sum(tabl$lengths[as.integer(tabl$values) %% 2 == 0])

Comment: You know that the string is longer than 100 characters and when you removing sth a number at position 101 is moved to thePosition 100. This number might be even .

Comment: Try with other answers.

Comment: Of course if the deleted one is before position 100 which I assume was in your case.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I do really appreciate your support, I'm trying to learn, I mean if you delete three 2s, then the count should be reduced from 51 to 48, but it will only be reduced to 50!

Comment: I do not know which numbers you remove position on the left or right. So on the right on position 100 will have not effect where on the left as we already discussed. Remember that when removing on the left of position 100 then new numbers could be even or odd.

Comment: I deleted three 2s on both sides (left and right of 100) but I'm getting the same results, it suppose to go down by 3 if on the left, but I'm getting 50 (only one fewer)!